# How does the community here define a partial answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I request the community to let me know:

- How does it define a partial answer?
- What should be the minimum information a partial answer should include?
- In what circumstances a partial answer should be deleted?
- The reasoning for deleting my answer in respect to the case I've mentioned below.

---

The [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) states that:

> #### Have the same problem?
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by **researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer**. That way, even if we can't figure it out, **the next person has more to go on**. You can also vote up the question or set a bounty on it so the question gets more attention.

There are related questions on Meta.SE as well:

- [Should I answer the question with just a partial solution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72392)
- [Is it okay to put partial answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144452/286110)
- [Should I downvote partial answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118640/286110)

---

### What's your central issue?

I posted an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78513/90094) (partial IMO) to this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78283/90094). To my surprise, the answer got deleted with a message:

> Although this information may be useful you should not post it as an answer. If you feel that this is a different question then post it as a question. Otherwise add this information in to the original question as a suggested edit. thanks!

High rep users would be able to see that deleted answer as well as the note that I made at the very beginning:

> This is not an answer, but has further information that may help someone to answer the question.

---

### What are you expecting now?

Not that I've any issue here with anyone who closed or flagged it, but I cannot fathom **how my answer does not** (*as per the help center content I quoted above*) **qualify as a partial answer**? To my understanding, it does it very well.

---

### Why can't you follow the advice given in the message by Mod?

> If you feel that this is a different question then post it as a question.

This is not a different question, so it would not make sense for me posting a duplicate question at all.

> Otherwise add this information in to the original question as a suggested edit.

I'm certain it will be rejected even if I make a note in the suggested edit that it's research. **The reviewers are not bound to reflect the Mod's understanding anywhere** (especially when they're unaware of the issue here).

Also, the [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/editing) states about editing as:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> [...]
>
> Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include **additional information only found in comments**, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

I don't think my edit would meet any criteria quoted above. So editing that existing question is a strict no for me.

Note that a Mod can do so, but they would've already done that when encountered my answer considering their wisdom/experience on the subjects here.

---

#### Original deleted answer for those who can't see it

> *This is not an answer, but has further information that may help someone to answer the question.*
>
> ---
>
> I use three profiles regularly on Firefox (v38.0.5) for Linux, and added two new profiles to reproduce the issue OP has.
>
> Scenario 1
>
> 1. Created Profile 1, and added no addon/plugin. Default profile from scratch to be precise. (No other profile is running except this one.)
> 2. Launched **Private browsing** and opened `gmail.com`
> 3. Logged in (two-step verification) with **Stay signed in** checked. Note that I didn't check **Don't ask for codes again on this computer** for two-step verification.
> 4. Relaunched Firefox and repeated step 2.
> 5. As OP said, as soon as I entered my email ID and clicked **Next**, Gmail detected my name registered with account.
>
> Scenario 2
>
> 1. Created Profile 2, and added no addon/plugin. Default profile from scratch to be precise. (No other profile is running except this one.)
> 2. Launched **Private browsing** and opened `gmail.com`
> 3. Logged in (two-step verification) without **Stay signed in** checked. Note that I didn't check **Don't ask for codes again on this computer** for two-step verification.
> 4. Relaunched Firefox and repeated step 2.
> 5. As OP said, as soon as I entered my email ID and clicked **Next**, Gmail detected my name registered with account.
>
> It must be noted that there is no trace of any browsing history (including Form history) which means I cannot delete or forget any site since they were never visited in default Firefox browsing mode.
>
> Is this some kind of terrible feature of Firefox, a bug, or Google seems to show the name based on User-agent I guess.
>
> Regardless of what it is, how do I get rid of it?
>
> ---
>
> Update 1: There are two things that I found very interesting. IDT whether Firefox is the reason or the Google itself is doing it, but here it is -- You do not get to see the name in Private browsing if:
>
> - you change the IP address (I use two different carriers)
> - you tweak the User-agent to something that makes no sense (like `weB.32.x64.ApplicationS`) -- in this case, Gmail throws both Email and Password field at once, and doesn't detect the name, no matter what.
>
> ---
>
> Update 2: Chromium for Linux rather behaved differently here. It reproduced the issue for one IP but not for the other (tried multiple times). I think Google has something to do here.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the answer and in hindsight this was an error. It was perhaps, on reflection, a hasty decision.

Sorry, I made a mistake. I have reinstated your answer.

Apologies for any confusion caused, please keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a big relief! On a side note, does the meta here has questions pertaining to the general three questions(points) I asked in this question? 

Also, I see two choices now: either I remove my case (now obsolete) and make the questions general (see the first three questions). Or, delete/flag it altogether for being absolutely obsolete.

What do you recommend?

Comment: You are talking about the question here on meta right? Just leave it as it is, all good here.